# Refactoring method with ugly conditions statements

Tags: java, refactoring

I have clumsy method with multiple ugly conditions statements. For Example:

```
public String getKafkaTopicName(EvntMsg evntMsg) {
    Table table = fillerTableSection(evntMsg);
    String[] msgDetails = table.getMessageString().split("\\^");
    String topicName;
    if (("QUEUE_R".equals(table.getDeliveryChannel()) && "A".equals(msgDetails[0])) ||
            ("M".equals(table.getDeliveryChannel()) && "F".equals(msgDetails[0])) ||
            ("QUEUE_Q".equals(table.getDeliveryChannel()) && "S".equals(msgDetails[0])) ||
            ("QUEUE_W".equals(table.getDeliveryChannel()) && "S".equals(msgDetails[0])) ||
            ("QUEUE_Q".equals(table.getDeliveryChannel()) && "C".equals(msgDetails[0]) && "DD_SRC_MESS".equals(table.getCode())) ||
            ("QUEUE_Q".equals(table.getDeliveryChannel()) && "C".equals(msgDetails[0]) && "DD_TGT_MESS".equals(table.getCode()))) {
        topicName = paramsHelper.getKafkaTopicNameBalance();
    } else if (("SMS3DS_CHECK".equals(table.getDeliveryChannel())) ||
            ("SMS3DS".equals(table.getDeliveryChannel()))) {
        topicName = paramsHelper.getKafkaTopicNameOtp();
    } else if (("SBRF_I".equals(table.getDeliveryChannel()) && "I".equals(msgDetails[0])) ||
            ("SBRF_B".equals(table.getDeliveryChannel()) && "B".equals(msgDetails[0])) ) {
        topicName = paramsHelper.getKafkaTopicNameIssuing();
    } else if (("QUEUE_Q".equals(table.getDeliveryChannel()) && "C".equals(msgDetails[0]) && "C0".equals(table.getCode().substring(0, 2))) ||
            ("QUEUE_R".equals(table.getDeliveryChannel()) && "AP".equals(msgDetails[0])) ||
            ("QUEUE_D".equals(table.getDeliveryChannel()) && "AP".equals(msgDetails[0]))) {
        topicName = paramsHelper.getKafkaTopicNameNotify();
    } else {
        topicName = paramsHelper.getKafkaTopicNameUndefined();
    }
    return topicName;
}
```

How it can be modified to improve readability?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is isolating in methods that return boolean

```
boolean test0(Table table, String[] msgDetails){
   return "QUEUE_R".equals(table.getDeliveryChannel()) && "A".equals(msgDetails[0])) ||
            ("M".equals(table.getDeliveryChannel()) && "F".equals(msgDetails[0])) ||
            ("QUEUE_Q".equals(table.getDeliveryChannel()) && "S".equals(msgDetails[0])) ||
            ("QUEUE_W".equals(table.getDeliveryChannel()) && "S".equals(msgDetails[0])) ||
            ("QUEUE_Q".equals(table.getDeliveryChannel()) && "C".equals(msgDetails[0]) && "DD_SRC_MESS".equals(table.getCode())) ||
            ("QUEUE_Q".equals(table.getDeliveryChannel()) && "C".equals(msgDetails[0]) && "DD_TGT_MESS".equals(table.getCode()))
}
```